# Nextjs 13, MDX-components file can't access data

Tags: next.js13, mdxjs

I have using nextjs 13.4.4 app directory in my current project, and i have render MDX on my nextjs project, and now I want to render element from MDX after replaching with some data from my mdx-components.tsx file. But unforcunatly I can't access of any data

here's inside of the code you can see I have try to get h1 element from MDX but It can't acces anything, and this file is not render anything in browser

```
import type { MDXComponents } from "mdx/types";

// This file allows you to provide custom React components
// to be used in MDX files. You can import and use any
// React component you want, including components from
// other libraries.

// This file is required to use MDX in `app` directory.
export function useMDXComponents(components: MDXComponents): MDXComponents {
  return {
    // Allows customizing built-in components, e.g. to add styling.
    h1: ({ children }) => <h1> - {children} </h1>,
    ...components,
    // code: SyntaxHighlight,
    // code: SyntaxHighlight,
  };
}
```